# решение ошибок LNK2019 , LNK2001 , LNK1120

Tags: c++, ооп

Уже в который раз встречаю ошибки LNK2019, LNK2001, LNK1120.

main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    
    #include "Kilometer.h"
    #include "Meter.h"
    #include "Decimeter.h"
    #include "Centimeter.h"
    
    
    
    #define MAX 10
    int  main() {
        Kilometer* arr[MAX]; //масив покажчиків на базовий клас
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) { arr[i] = NULL; } //обнулення масиву
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 3 == 1 || i % 3 == 2) {
                arr[i] = new Centimeter(1 + rand() % MAX);
            } else if (i % 3 == 3 || i % 3 == 4 || i % 3 == 5 || i%3 == 10)
                arr[i] = new Decimeter(1 + rand() % MAX);
            else if (i % 3 == 6 || i % 3 == 7 || i % 3 == 8 || i% 3 == 9 )
                arr[i] = new Meter(1 + rand() % MAX);
            arr[i] -> Square();
            arr[i] -> Out();          //виклик методів для елементів масиву
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++ )
            if( arr[i] ) delete arr[i]; //очищення масиву
        return 0;
    }
```

Kilometer.h

```
    
        #pragma once
        class Kilometer{
        protected:
            double length;
        public:
            Kilometer (double length=0);
            virtual ~Kilometer () = 0;
            virtual void Out() = 0;
            virtual double Square() = 0;
        
        }
    
    ;
```

Meter.h

```
    #pragma once
    #include "Kilometer.h"
    class Meter: public Kilometer{
    public:
        Meter(double length);
        ~Meter() ;
        double Square();
        void Out();
    }

;
```

Decimeter.h

```
    #pragma once
    #include "Kilometer.h"
    
    class Decimeter: public Kilometer{
    public:
        Decimeter(double length);
        ~Decimeter();
        double Square();
        void Out();
    };
```

Centimeter.h

```
    #pragma once
    #include "Kilometer.h"
    
    class Centimeter: public Kilometer{
    public:
        Centimeter(double length);
        ~Centimeter();
        double Square();
        void Out();
    };
```

Kilometer.cpp

```
    #include "Kilometer.h"
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    Kilometer::Kilometer(double length) {
        this->length = length;
    }
```

Meter.cpp

```
    
        #include <iostream>
        #include "Meter.h"
        using namespace std;
        
        Meter::Meter(double length) : Kilometer(length)
        {
            this->length = length;
        }
        Meter::~Meter(){}
        double Meter::Square()
        {
            return length * 1000 * 1000;
        }
        void Meter::Out()
        {
           cout<<"the square area in meters is :\t"<<Square()<<endl;
        }
```

Decimeter.cpp

````
```
````

#include 
#include "Decimeter.h"
using namespace std;

```
Decimeter::Decimeter(double length) : Kilometer(length)
{
    this->length = length;
}
Decimeter::~Decimeter(){}
double Decimeter::Square()
{
    return length * 10000 * 10000;
}
void Decimeter::Out()
{
    cout<<"the square area in decimeters is :\t"<<Square()<<endl;
}
```

```
Centimeter.cpp
```

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include "Centimeter.h"
        using namespace std;
        
        Centimeter::Centimeter(double length) : Kilometer(length)
        {
            this->length = length;
        }
        Centimeter::~Centimeter(){};
        double Centimeter::Square()
        {
            return length * 100000 * 100000;
        }
        void Centimeter::Out()
        {
            cout<<"the square area in centimeters is :\t"<<Square()<<endl;
        }
```

[image: и выходит такое]

Answer (score 1):

Понимаете, с деструктором ваш фокус

```
virtual ~Kilometer () = 0;
```

не проканает: деструктор предка должен вызываться обязательно. Вот и все ваши проблемы...

```
virtual ~Kilometer () {};
```

вполне сойдет.

Comment: `.. = default ;` - короче и быстрее.

Comment: @AlexGlebe 8 символов короче двух? 8-/